# How to get html request URL in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Am using a HTML form like this,

```
<form action="/myservlet?userid=12345" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the path of this HTML form is say for example, http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html

In my servlet when i use the `String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();` and printout the string it prints the form action URL http://www.mywebapp.com/myservlet?userid=12345 and not the HTML URL.

The expected HTML URL : http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html (from here only i request and i need this URL)

Can anyone suggest me how to get the HTML url path in the servlet.

Comment: did you try to use `getRequestURI().toString();` ?

Comment: What do you mean by the *HTML URL*? Do you excepted to get `/myservlet?userid=12345`?

Comment: paste the example string here that which you mean html url path..so that someone helps you .

Comment: @KevinEsche if i use `getRequestURI().toString();` am getting only `/myservlet` Am expecting to get the `http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html`

Comment: @sp00m No am expecting to get `http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the URL of one request (the request that loaded the html) when you make a subsequent request (the `form` post).

HTTP is stateless and therefore there is no way to reliably do this.

Needing to do this has a bit of a whiff of a code smell about it, but if you really need the URL you're going to have to pass the URL as a hidden `input` in the `form`.  There's various ways to do this, whether you use JSP/JSTL or do something client side with JavaScript, but basically you trying to get a `form` like this:

```
<form action="/myservlet?userid=12345" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly. The problem i face here is client may use any device and from that HTML page request will be send to my servlet. So its not possible for me to ask client to send the URL as Hidden. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Persumably if you don't control the client html then it is being loaded from another webapp or even server?  If it was in the same webapp you might have been able to do something with a session, but doesn't sound like that's the case.  The bottom line is that if the URL is important to the servlet then it's one of the parameters required by the servlet and any client will have to adhere to that just as they do the other parameters.

Comment: When i use `multipart/form-data` am getting the hidden field value as null in servlet can you tell how to solve it

Comment: Sorry, I copied the `from` from your original question - you can drop the `multipart/form-data` bit.  I'd then start by hardcoding the value, then once that works I'd set the value using the *JSTL* url tag.

Comment: Nick i got that link successfully. Now i want to dispatch the output to the URL which is passed as hidden. I tried with Request Dispatcher but am failing can give idea in that

Comment: If the `RequestDispatcher` is used to *forward* the request to another resource on the server, something normally done with `GET` requests.  Given your form is a `POST` and the `url` parameter potentially points to a request on another server I think you want to use a `redirect`.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

Comment: yes but redirect shows 302 status which should not happen. Can you see this link i just posted that problem here...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459574/how-to-forward-the-requestdispatcher-to-a-remote-url/14459657#comment20139318_14459657

Answer (score 3):

It's some kind of problem, because user loaded, as you write, page `http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html` and at this initial request you will get from `request.getRequestURL().toString` exactly this value

On next request with use a form (from client side) url is not anymore this `http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html` but the one specified in `form action` atributte.

There are many suggestion of passing hidden value in form or something like this, but you can easly make use of simple HTTP. Everytime when you do GET request you get a new URL in your browser (or other client) window but when you do POST request URL in browser doesn't change. So now in your code if you know that this is a POST request and you want to get page from where this request is comming you can easly read it from Http Header "Referer" as:

```
String URLfromWherePostWasMade = request.getHeader("Referer");
```

This should work the same as all "hidden field" examples

Comment: +1 - Doh, wish I'd have thought about the HTTP headers before I answered (answer now deleted as it's misleading).

Comment: Heh, but my suggestions will only work in client environment where http referer value is managed. Of course such environments are all web browser which I know.

Comment: Though watch out for this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer#Referer_hiding

Comment: Yes, like I said - it will work only in common, standard user environment, mostly web browsers

Comment: ya but when i try it in https am getting null value my search on that issue http://allben.net/post/2009/02/25/Null-Url-Referrer-going-from-HTTPS-to-HTTP

Comment: Yes, it's a none started with https due to the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'HTML Page' is called the "Referrer" and you can get it in this way

```
HttpServletRequest.getHeader("Referer");
```

It will return the page where the form has been submitted, in your case

```
http://www.mywebapp.com/sample.html
```

Comment: I tried with it but if its HTTPS den it returns null value see this link http://allben.net/post/2009/02/25/Null-Url-Referrer-going-from-HTTPS-to-HTTP

Comment: If it returns a null value, it means that the HTTP referrer was not filled. HTTP referrer is filled by the browser, and HTTPS connections don't have a http referrer: `Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol` So you cannot do it if you use a HTTPS connection. Source:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3