# Url redirection according to the user name in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, forward

I need to redirect the url according to the username in the url.

Let say, url is of the form of

get http://192.168.2.0/user1/app/node-id/info

then,

it should redirect this url to different server like,

get http://192.168.2.1/app/node-id/info

The client should be unaware of the fact, it is being redirected.
He/She should see the same url, but the response should come from the redirected url in Json or html format.

Which we can perform via request forwarding.

Every where I am able to see the solution servlet way.
What is the best way to do it spring way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java servlets have redirect and forward methods. Difference between them are explained on [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181) and you can use them as below; redirect changes the url but forward processes the request internal.

If you want to redirect users to a remote url check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14459574/517134) and maybe to redirect without changing browser's address, the easy way is reading it with [url](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) and writing it to response on servlet

```
private void redirect(ResponsePage aDestinationPage, HttpServletResponse aResponse) throws IOException {
    String urlWithSessionID = aResponse.encodeRedirectURL(aDestinationPage.toString());
    aResponse.sendRedirect( urlWithSessionID );
}

private void forward(ResponsePage aResponsePage, HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = aRequest.getRequestDispatcher(aResponsePage.toString());
    dispatcher.forward(aRequest, aResponse);
}
```

In addition for usernames on url addresses, you can use [filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) and redirect them as your wish. For using spring with filter please check [here](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.tr/2013/07/filters-and-spring.html) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/)

Comment: Is there any special spring way to forward the request?

Comment: I think filters solve your problem. For using spring with filter please check the http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.tr/2013/07/filters-and-spring.html and http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/